# Why is strlen() slower than use of variable when string size does not matter

Tags: php, performance, strlen

I was writing some simple file manipulation and a thought came up if it wouldn't be faster if I saved the string size in variable. It showed up that it is 10 times faster.
Using this code:

```
include "../classes/Timer.class.php";
$t = new Timer();             //Timer class I've written for this purpose [link below]
$multiplyer = 3000000;        //Times to try the operation
$string = str_repeat("ggggggggggg",2);  //I first tried 2000 here, but for 2 there are same results
$t("calling");     //Saving time
for($i=0; $i<$multiplyer; $i++) {
  $size =  strlen($string);
  $size2 = strlen($string);
  $size3 = strlen($string);
}
$t("clover");
$t("caching");     //Saving time
for($i=0; $i<$multiplyer; $i++) {
  $size =  strlen($string);
  $size2 = $size;
  $size3 = $size;
}
$t("chover");
$total = $t["calling-clover"]+$t["caching-chover"];  //percents are usefull :)
echo "Calling: {$t["calling-clover"]} (".round(($t["calling-clover"]/$total)*100)."%)<br>\n";
echo "Caching in variables: {$t["caching-chover"]} (".round(($t["caching-chover"]/$total)*100)."%)<br>\n";
```

#### Results:

> Calling: 1.988455057 (67%)
>   Caching in variables: 0.984993458 (33%)

What is even more interesting is the fact, that it does not matter what number I put in the `str_repeat` call, so the `strlen` obviously does not compute anything - the size must be saved somewhere and `strlen` is just function that returns value.
This implies:
**Are really function calls so slow?**
**If not, is this `strlen` specific?**

---

[Timer.class.php](http://u8.8u.cz/code/Timer.class.php)

Comment: What's the most amazing is how PHP is seemingly unable to apply some optimization to this loop.

Comment: PHP strings can contain nulls (e.g. raw binary data), so a standard C-style strlen would fail and under-report the length. It's not zero-cost, but strlen is basically an O(1) operation.

Comment: Are the 3 million string length probes really your only code, or wouldn't the file saving be more relevant?

Comment: Of course a function call is more expensive than a variable assignment, especially when the variable already exists and its value is simply being overwritten with a value of the same type (no create or memory allocation needed)

Comment: @MarkBaker: it showed up as **10** times slower. And the there are 3 different variables in both loops (`size1`, `size2`, `size3`).

Comment: In your second (caching) loop all 3 variables you're using ($size, $size2, and $size3) already exist (even in the first iteration) so you're simply assigning new values of the same size/type.... it's not really a valid comparison. Simple assignment will always be faster than a function call, but your pre-existing variables are making it seem even faster than it would be in a real world script. Try assigning new array elements each iteration (if memory can take it)

Comment: @MarkBaker: I thought that variables initialised within loops are deinitialised after iteration.

Comment: @Tomas, nope, never have been deinitialised, not in PHP, nor are they ever likely to be.... defined in a function, they're deinitialised when they're out of scope (function exits) but only then

Comment: @MarkBaker: Ok, thank you for this information. Adding `unset` didn't change the results, but I will keep this fact in mind.

Comment: @ring0 - if one were to use a an optimiser like [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or the Zend Optimiser, it would. Anyone thinking about optimising their PHP code should start by installing one of these products before they start micro-optimising their code as per this question.

Comment: unset() will have an overhead, but it's a language construct rather than a function so it's less of an overhead than calling strlen()

Comment: @TomášZato - it's worth pointing out that while benchmarks like this can prove that method A is faster than method B, unless your real code is doing a large loop like the benchmark, you're unlikely to have any performance issues resulting from using `strlen()` in your everyday code. The odds are that your code does have bottlenecks, but it's probably not here. Your time would be better spent finding the real bottlenecks and dealing with them, rather than fiddling over microscopic optimisations that will have no noticable effect on your real-world performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is much more to a function call than a variable retrieval. Every time you execute a function:

1. A new stack is created and arguments to the function are stored on the stack.
2. Memory is allocated on the stack for the return value of the function
3. The previously allocated memory address is stored on the stack
4. The address of the function is called
5. The function reads the arguments from the stack
6. Return value is stored in the stack
7. Execution is restored to the caller and the stack is cleared

Answer (score 8):

This is more in compliment to Colin's answer

> What is even more interesting is the fact, that it does not matter what number I put in the str_repeat call, so the strlen obviously does not compute anything - the size must be saved somewhere and strlen is just function that returns value.

This is correct. After diving through the source for quite a while, I've ended up at this line:

```
#define Z_STRLEN(zval)                  (zval).value.str.len
```

So yes, the value of strlen is computed once and cached.

Comment: Interesting thank you for this note. I've voted this +1, thank you once more.